# Gauss Elimination from kirchoff's Law Circuit

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

In this system there are three magnitudes of current flowing 1,
2, and 3 in the appropriate direction
on picture.

[image: electricity circuit picture]

a. Set up a system of linear equations that can represent the problem of electrical circuits
with the help of Kirchoff's law.

b. Determine the magnitude of the electric current 1,
2, and 3 by solving the system of equations
obtained in problem (a) using Gauss/Gauss-Jordan elimination.

Can anyone please check my answer:

> I deleted my answer which consist the full solution since it might cause this post getting deleted.

Comment: I think this is a physics question, you can post it here https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unfortunately they deleted my post in the physics stackexchange

Comment: Are you supposed to use Loop method or Junction method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your answer you have uploaded, you have made a slight mistake in the third row.

Omitting the units, the KVL equation you should be getting is:
$$
\begin{align}
90 & = 15i_3+10i_2+10i_3 \\
& =10i_2+25i_3 \\
\end{align}
$$
This can be further reduced to:
$$
\begin{align}
2i_2+5i_3 & = 18 \\
\end{align}
$$
Hence, the corresponding KCL and KVL equations you have to form is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 5\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
i_1\\
i_2\\
i_3\\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
8\\
18\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I leave you to solve for the currents. You should be getting $i_1 = 2A, i_2 = 4A$ and $i_3 = 2A$. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

By KCL at junction Q (or P):

$$i_2 = i_1 +i_3$$

The potential difference across QP in the three branches are equal and by using Ohm's law:

$$-20i_1 +80V = +10i_2 = -10i_3 + 90V + 15i_3$$

You have 3 independent equations in 3 variables, $i_1, i_2, i_3$ that you can solve using Gaussian elimination.